# Passing a double pointer to a function as reference - c

Tags: c, function, pointers, reference, double

I'm having hard times trying to pass the reference of double pointer to a function.
I have this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>   
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_ROWS 2
#define MAX_COLS 2

int main(void){
    int i=0,lenght=0,maxColumns=0,j=0,k=0,maxRows=0,maxColumns2=0;
    int **columnVect;
        /*lengthOfPtr gives me the columns that i need. */
    if((lenght=(lengthOfPtr(ptrMessage)))<=3){
        maxColumns=1;
        maxColumns2=2;
    }else{
        maxColumns=lenght/2;
        maxColumns2=maxColumns;
    }
        /* Allocating Memory for the double pointer. */
    columnVect=malloc(maxColumns2 * sizeof(int*));
    if(columnVect == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory error.\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < maxColumns2; i++){
        columnVect[i] = malloc(maxRows * sizeof(int));
        if(columnVect[i] == NULL){
            fprintf(stderr, "Memory error.\n");
            exit(0);
        }
    }

    // Do something that fills columnVect[i][j]

        /* Passing the double pointer to messageVector */
    messageVector(&columnVect,maxColumns);
return 0;
}


int messageVector(int ***columnVect,int maxColumns){
        /* Allocating Memory for the triple pointer. */
    columnVect=(int ***)malloc(sizeof(int **)); 

   //Do something here . . . 

return messageVector;
}
```

If i run the program gives me: (lldb)

In:

3 start
libdyld.dylib`start:
0x7fff88b447e0:  nop

Anyone could tell me how to do this in the correct way?  Thanks!

Comment: What is purpose of `messageVector` function, do you want to change the double pointer allocated earlier? If not you don't have to allocate it.

Comment: Yes, perhaps anyone could tell you the solution if the code was readable and small enough.

Comment: The purpose is to multiply the value returned.

Comment: From just a quick browsing, I think you should `*columnVect = malloc( sizeof(int *) )` instead of `columnVect=(int ***)malloc(sizeof(int **));` inside the `messageVector()` function. That is, since you want to pass a double-pointer by reference (although I don't get why you want to allocate it again inside that function... it is already allocated in the caller, plus you create a memory leak because you do not free its previous allocated memory)

Comment: C has no notion of pass by reference.  Everything is passed by value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, although I do not quite understand what you are trying to accomplish with the `messageVector` function, I think your question is a legitimate one, thus I'll try to give you some insight.

First of all, there is another issue with the code you have presented in the `main` function. If `malloc` fails while you're allocating `maxColumns2` rows, you exit without `free`ing any previously allocated rows.

Please note that I have deliberately swapped the wording of `maxColumns2` and `maxRows`, because in a general context it does a bit more sense. Conceptually, you start by allocating rows of `int` pointers, and then for each row you allocate columns of `int`.

So, you may try something like this instead...

```
/* Allocating Memory for the double pointer. */

columnVect = malloc( maxRows * sizeof(int *) );
if ( columnVect == NULL ){
    fputs( "Memory error.\n", stderr );
    exit(0);
}

for (int i=0; i < maxRows; i++)
{
    columnVect[i] = malloc( maxColumns2 * sizeof(int) );
    if ( columnVect[i] == NULL )
    {
        fputs( "Memory error.\n", stderr );
        for (int j = i-1; j > -1; j--)
            free( columnVect[j] );
        free( columnVect );
        columnVect = NULL;
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

The inner loop (using the `j` counter) walks from the last successfully allocated row towards the 1st one, `free`ing them up on the way. After that, `columnsVect` is also gets `free`'ed (that is, the memory reserved for the `int` pointers before the outer loop) and it's set to `NULL`.

I'm probably nitpicking here, since most modern operating systems will free up any memory allocated by your program after it terminates, but it's a good habit to always free the memory you have allocated. For one thing, it helps when debugging your code. It also protects you from creating memory leaks in the future, if you need to embed your current code into a larger project (a library for example).

Now, regarding passing the reference of a double pointer into a function, a nice and simple example imho would be a function that frees up the memory reserved for that pointer, and setting the pointer to `NULL`. Something along these lines:

```
void free_int2d( int ***int2d, int nrows )
{
    int i;

    if ( nrows < 1 ) {
        printf( "*** warning: %s() failed, no memory freed\n", __func__ );
        return;
    }
    if ( !int2d || !*int2d )
        return;

    for (i=0; i < nrows; i++) {
        if ( (*int2d)[i] )
            free( (*int2d)[i] );
    }

    *int2d = NULL;
}
```

Hopefully it is self-explanatory, but just in case let me point out a few things.

The main one is to write `*int2d` whenever you want to express your original double pointer inside the function (that is, the rows of `int` pointers).

The other one is that when you want to express the `i`'th row, you write `(*int2d)[i]`. You have to explicitly enclose the 1st dereference inside parenthesis... the 2nd dereference is done implicitly via the [ ] notation.

Finally, as an example of passing by reference a double pointer to this function, here is the inner loop of the original code, rewritten using this `free_int2` function...

```
for (int i=0; i < maxRows; i++)
{
    columnVect[i] = malloc( maxColumns2 * sizeof(int) );
    if ( columnVect[i] == NULL )
    {
        fputs( "Memory error.\n", stderr );
        free_int2d( &columnVect, i );
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

It is substantially simplified, thus more readable. `free_2d( &columnVect, maxRows )` should also get called on successful termination of the program (for the reasons I explained above).

**EDIT**

For performance reasons, you may consider pre-allocating a buffer for `malloc`ing the columns, and reallocate it as needed (perhaps by doubling its size). But this yields to a bit more complicated code.